how to add extern jvm arguments to gradle task `:quarkusIntTest`?
My application (gradle/quarkus) needs to specify several jvm parameters in order to function properly.
I have to set these parameters to several gradle tasks.

tasks {
    withType<Test> {
        systemProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
        jvmArgs("--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED", "--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED")
    }

    withType<QuarkusDev> {
        jvmArguments.addAll(
            "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
            "--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED",
        )
    }
    
    withType<QuarkusRun> {
        jvmArguments.addAll(
            "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
            "--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED",
        )
    }


It works.
But I don't know how to set them to the ':quarkusIntTest' task.

There is an option: quarkus.test.arg-line.
quarkus.test.arg-line="--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED"

